# Parse JSON object in C# without using class

Tags: c#, json

I have two string values in a JSON object. I want to call this method in same class and use the values without using class.

I am using the following method:

```
public JsonResult Details()
{
    return Json(new { Data = "DisplayName", result = "UniqueName" });
}
```

I need to use this data and result value in another method.

I am getting the value like:

```
var Details = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Details());
```

My output is:

```
{
    \"ContentEncoding\": null,
    \"ContentType\": null,
    \"Data\": {
        \"Data\": \"DisplayName\",
        \"result\": \"UniqueName\"
    },
    \"JsonRequestBehavior\": 1,
    \"MaxJsonLength\": null,
    \"RecursionLimit\": null
}
```

How do I get the data and result value from this?

Comment: Be specific. Show what you have tried so far and post a clear problem statement.

Comment: I have tried by below method to get data value. But I am getting the error which is also I mentioned below.
var Details = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Details());

Details["Data"];

'string' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
details["Data"]

Comment: `Serializing` will give you string, if you want to get something like property and it's value kind, then the data need to be in the object form. Try `deserializing` that string.

Comment: But I don't need any class to deserialize it. How to deserialize this without using class ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3142495/3788456

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method which you are using (i.e:)

```
public JsonResult Details()
{
    return Json(new { Data = "DisplayName", result = "UniqueName" });
}
```

returns a `JsonResult` object which has a property named `Data`, i.e `Details().Data`, which contains the data your object contains. So in order to get your object's `Data` and `result` values, you need to serialize it again.

This is the full solution:

```
JsonResult json = Details();                         // returns JsonResult type object
string ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json.Data); // serializing JsonResult object (it will give you json string)
object dec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ser);     // deserializing Json string (it will deserialize Json string)
JObject obj =  JObject.Parse(dec.ToString());        // it will parse deserialize Json object
string name = obj["Data"].ToString();                // now after parsing deserialize Json object you can get individual values by key i.e.

string name = obj["Data"].ToString();       // will give Data value
string name = obj["result"].ToString();     // will give result value
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

By looking at `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, I guess you are using `NewtonSoft` dll. In that you have `JObject.Parse` under `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` which you can import (`using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`). You can parse that json string as

`var details = JObject.Parse(your_json_string);`

This will give you `JObject` and you can get the details as

`var data = details["Data"].ToString();`

Comment: Hi, If I have multiple data inside the json object, How to get that value ??
public JsonResult Details()
     {
         return
             Json(
                 new
                 {
                     Data =
                         "{'displayname':'display name 1','name':'Unique name 1'}, {'displayname':'display name 2','name':'Unique name 2'}"

                 });
     }

Comment: Even I have to do by trying it. I am not so much familiar with this.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonResult` already stores the object for you, under `Data`. It has not been serialized yet, it simply indicates to the `MVC` framework to serialize it to JSON when responding to a web request.

```
var details = Details().Data;
```

Of course, this will be typed as an object - which isn't too useful. You can cast it back to the anonymous type like this:

```
private T CastToAnonymous<T>(object obj, T anonymousType)
{
    return (T)obj;
}

var details = CastToAnonymous(Details().Data, 
     new { Data = string.Empty, result = string.Empty });
```

And then you can use it like...

```
var data = details.Data;
var result  = details.result;
```

And it will be type-safe.